# Is there a way to COUNT the amount of non-null between the NULLs in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is pulling financial figures and flags whether they have hit a target or not. I have a column that populates a 1 if the target is hit, and it NULLs if the target isn't hit. This is a simple CASE statement.

I need to be able count how many consecutive rows in that column are populated with a 1, and then stop counting when a NULL is hit, and then start counting again from the next non-null.

I have tried every combination of "COUNT(*) OVER" I can possibly think of, all not quite giving me the result I need.

I'll post the entire query as it's not too long -

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE
        WHEN zzz.Flag_hit_Target IS NOT NULL THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY zzz.Flag_hit_Target ORDER BY CAST(zzz.Close_month as DATE) DESC)  
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Counter
FROM
(   
    SELECT
        zz.Close_month,
        SUM(MRP) as Total_MRP,
        zz.Target,
        CASE
            WHEN SUM(MRP) >= zz.Target THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END AS Flag_hit_target
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Opp.id,
            opp.MRP__c as MRP,
            1500 as Target,
            CONCAT(DATENAME(month, Closedate), ' ', DATEPART(year, Closedate)) as Close_month
        FROM Table1 as Opp WITH (NOLOCK)    
        WHERE OPP_type__c = 'Opp Type 1'
        AND Appointment_setter1__c = 'Person 1'
        AND Stagename = 'Closed (Won)'
    ) as zz
    GROUP BY zz.Close_month, zz.Target
) as zzz
ORDER by CAST(zzz.Close_month as DATE) desc
```

With this I get the following results -

```
+----------------+-----------------+---------+
|  Close_month   | Flag_hit_target | Counter |
+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| June 2019      | NULL            | NULL    |
| April 2019     | NULL            | NULL    |
| March 2019     | 1               | 1       |
| February 2019  | NULL            | NULL    |
| January 2019   | 1               | 2       |
| November 2018  | NULL            | NULL    |
| October 2018   | NULL            | NULL    |
| September 2018 | NULL            | NULL    |
| July 2018      | NULL            | NULL    |
| June 2018      | 1               | 3       |
| May 2018       | NULL            | NULL    |
| April 2018     | 1               | 4       |
| March 2018     | NULL            | NULL    |
| February 2018  | 1               | 5       |
| January 2018   | 1               | 6       |
| December 2017  | 1               | 7       |
| October 2017   | NULL            | NULL    |
| September 2017 | 1               | 8       |
| August 2017    | 1               | 9       |
| July 2017      | 1               | 10      |
| June 2017      | 1               | 11      |
| May 2017       | NULL            | NULL    |
| April 2017     | 1               | 12      |
| March 2017     | NULL            | NULL    |
| February 2017  | 1               | 13      |
| January 2017   | 1               | 14      |
+----------------+-----------------+---------+
```

The results I am after is as following (notice the end column) -

```
+----------------+-----------------+---------+
|  Close_month   | Flag_hit_target | Counter |
+----------------+-----------------+---------+
| June 2019      | NULL            | NULL    |
| April 2019     | NULL            | NULL    |
| March 2019     | 1               | 1       |
| February 2019  | NULL            | NULL    |
| January 2019   | 1               | 1       |
| November 2018  | NULL            | NULL    |
| October 2018   | NULL            | NULL    |
| September 2018 | NULL            | NULL    |
| July 2018      | NULL            | NULL    |
| June 2018      | 1               | 1       |
| May 2018       | NULL            | NULL    |
| April 2018     | 1               | 1       |
| March 2018     | NULL            | NULL    |
| February 2018  | 1               | 3       |
| January 2018   | 1               | 2       |
| December 2017  | 1               | 1       |
| October 2017   | NULL            | NULL    |
| September 2017 | 1               | 4       |
| August 2017    | 1               | 3       |
| July 2017      | 1               | 2       |
| June 2017      | 1               | 1       |
| May 2017       | NULL            | NULL    |
| April 2017     | 1               | 1       |
| March 2017     | NULL            | NULL    |
| February 2017  | 1               | 2       |
| January 2017   | 1               | 1       |
+----------------+-----------------+---------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have time atm, but check #5 of this article: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/04/25/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible/

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Thank you sir, this looks promising. I'll have a go now. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use a `ROW_NUMBER` for all records, and substract the `ROW_NUMBER` value of the last `NULL` record for each date.

**Setup**:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Test

CREATE TABLE #Test (
    Date DATE,
    Flag BIT)

INSERT INTO #Test (
    Date,
    Flag)
VALUES
    ('2019-09-01', NULL),
    ('2019-08-01', NULL),
    ('2019-07-01', 1),
    ('2019-06-01', NULL),
    ('2019-05-01', 1),
    ('2019-04-01', NULL),
    ('2019-03-01', NULL),
    ('2019-02-01', NULL),
    ('2019-01-01', 1),
    ('2018-12-01', NULL),
    ('2018-11-01', 1),
    ('2018-10-01', NULL),
    ('2018-09-01', 1),
    ('2018-08-01', 1),
    ('2018-07-01', 1),
    ('2018-06-01', NULL),
    ('2018-05-01', 1),
    ('2018-04-01', 1),
    ('2018-03-01', 1),
    ('2018-02-01', 1),
    ('2018-01-01', NULL)
```

**Solution**:

```
;WITH DataWithRowNumber AS
(
    SELECT
        T.*,
        RowNumber = -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.Date)
    FROM
        #Test AS T
)
SELECT
    D.Date,
    D.Flag,
    D.RowNumber,
    M.MaxPreviousNullRowNumber,
    RowNumberRest = D.RowNumber - M.MaxPreviousNullRowNumber,
    Counter = CASE WHEN D.Flag IS NOT NULL THEN D.RowNumber - M.MaxPreviousNullRowNumber END
FROM
    DataWithRowNumber AS D
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT
            MaxPreviousNullRowNumber = MAX(R.RowNumber)
        FROM
            DataWithRowNumber AS R
        WHERE
            R.Date < D.Date AND
            R.Flag IS NULL) AS M
ORDER By
    D.RowNumber DESC
```

**Result**:

```
+------------+------+-----------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+
|    Date    | Flag | RowNumber | MaxPreviousNullRowNumber | RowNumberRest | Counter |
+------------+------+-----------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+
| 2019-09-01 | NULL |        20 | 19                       | 1             | NULL    |
| 2019-08-01 | NULL |        19 | 17                       | 2             | NULL    |
| 2019-07-01 | 1    |        18 | 17                       | 1             | 1       |
| 2019-06-01 | NULL |        17 | 15                       | 2             | NULL    |
| 2019-05-01 | 1    |        16 | 15                       | 1             | 1       |
| 2019-04-01 | NULL |        15 | 14                       | 1             | NULL    |
| 2019-03-01 | NULL |        14 | 13                       | 1             | NULL    |
| 2019-02-01 | NULL |        13 | 11                       | 2             | NULL    |
| 2019-01-01 | 1    |        12 | 11                       | 1             | 1       |
| 2018-12-01 | NULL |        11 | 9                        | 2             | NULL    |
| 2018-11-01 | 1    |        10 | 9                        | 1             | 1       |
| 2018-10-01 | NULL |         9 | 5                        | 4             | NULL    |
| 2018-09-01 | 1    |         8 | 5                        | 3             | 3       |
| 2018-08-01 | 1    |         7 | 5                        | 2             | 2       |
| 2018-07-01 | 1    |         6 | 5                        | 1             | 1       |
| 2018-06-01 | NULL |         5 | 0                        | 5             | NULL    |
| 2018-05-01 | 1    |         4 | 0                        | 4             | 4       |
| 2018-04-01 | 1    |         3 | 0                        | 3             | 3       |
| 2018-03-01 | 1    |         2 | 0                        | 2             | 2       |
| 2018-02-01 | 1    |         1 | 0                        | 1             | 1       |
| 2018-01-01 | NULL |         0 | NULL                     | NULL          | NULL    |
+------------+------+-----------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: You legend, this is solid, I'll implement it now. Thank you, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Ryan you need to implement the sql running total here , please check the link

https://codingsight.com/calculating-running-total-with-over-clause-and-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server/

Comment: Please don't post answers that only contain link. Write most important part of the link in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh but I don't think that's quite what I'm after. Appreciate it all the same though.